# why my jquery codes doesn't run?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to toggle element that id's *pg* when click link.
header:

```
<title>Example</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $("#link").click(function() {
                    $("#pg").toggle();
            });
        </script>
```

Elements:

```
<p id="pg">deneme deneme 123 deneme</p>
<a href="#" id="link">toggle</a>
```

Comment: You can look for `errors` in your console.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing the final `});` for the statement

```
<title>Example</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $("#link").click(function() {
        $("#pg").toggle();
      });
    )}; //<-- Missing close bracket
  </script>
```

Also, if you're using Firefox, check out [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).  Its an invaluable debugger tool and will show you where errors are happening.

Chrome has a Developer Tools enabled, not sure about IE.

Comment: *not sure about IE.* just kick `F12`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, I stay away from IE as much as possible.  Unfortunately, that'll begin to change next month...

Answer (score 10):

close click function by adding `});`:

```
$(function() {
     $("#link").click(function() {
         $("#pg").toggle();
     });
});
```

Comment: As a quick add to the OP's comment here: that's not something specific to jQuery, the need to properly close each function is a general javascript need. Just figured I'd clarify that.